# StackOverFlow Exception in gridView_DataBindingComplete event

Tags: c#, windows

When I run following code I am getting StackOverFlow Exception.Please provide solution for this.

```
private void gridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        double percentageOfProfit = 0.00;
        if (gridView.Columns.Contains("TotalAmountPayable"))
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["PercentageOfProfit"].Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    percentageOfProfit = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["PercentageOfProfit"].Value);
                    row.Cells["AmountPayableToBeneficiary"].Value = totalRevenuePaid * (percentageOfProfit / 100.00);
                    row.Cells["TotalAmountPayable"].Value = totalRevenuePaid;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you comment out the line that updates the cell containing the "TotalAmountPayable" does the problem go away?

Comment: StackOverflowException is usually thrown when there is an infinite recusion. There is no direct recursion in your code but there can still be one when you take into account that accessing properties of the DataGridView can trigger events. If you have more event handlers for this DataGridView then try setting breakpoints in them to see if one causes that behaviour.